How to wrap all API-calls in a uniform error-handler?
I'm dealing with a vendor-provided C-library (let's call it foo), that offers a multitude of API-calls. All of these functions take a (pre-initialized) handle (of type FOOHandle) and return 0 on success, and some other number on failure. In the latter case, the caller can call the foo_get_errmsg() to get the textual description of the error saved in his own buffer. Nothing too unusual.
Programming in C++, I'd like to turn these errors into exception of my own type. To that end, I created my own class FOOException with the following constructor:
private:
    char    buf[1024];
    int     code;
public:
    FOOException(FOOHandle h, int32_t _code) noexcept : code(_code)
    {
        foo_get_errmsg(code, h, buf);
    }

So far so good.
To help convert existing code, I'd like to add a generic wrapper-function, which would invoke the specified API-call, check its result, then throw a new exception, if warranted:
    static auto wrapper(const auto &foofunc, auto&&... args) const
    {
        auto code = foofunc(args...);

        switch (code) {
        case 0:
            return 0;
        default:
            throw FOOException(handle, code);
        }
    }

My problem is in obtaining that handle... Though the argument is always present in all calls to the FOO-functions -- thus always among the args... -- it is not always the first:
        foo_analyze(a, handle);
...
        foo_meow(handle, a, b, c, d);

Is there some way I can "fish" the handle out from the args... (either by name or by type) for the wrapper to use too, or must I duplicate it in all calls to the wrapper() -- once for the wrapper itself, and then again for the function being wrapped?

How about a wrapper namespace that regularises the handle to always be the first argument. Introduce namespace std_foo and then have analyze() that is analyze(handle,a) it's a tiny bit of effort (though if compiled inline will have no overhead) and let's face it an API where the handle it's the first argument is a tiny bit eccentric wouldn't you say?

The problem domain seems to be actually larger than the question. I would provide a RAII wrapper for handles first; typically they would be move-only or none-movable. Functions that return error codes, normally return the actual result in a pointer argument; if that's the case, I would provide wrapper functions that return std::expected or 3rd party equivalent(boost::outcome) with int as the error type. Traditional exception handling - using try+catch - is no more the canon trend. Monadic classes are the recommended solution.

Assuming there is only one FooHandle from the Args, you might do something like (create std::tuple and extract by type):
auto& handle = std::get<FooHandle&>(std::tie(args...));

Demo

Neat... And the compiler would be smart enough to figure this out at compile time, woudn't it?

Yes, it is compile time.

handles in C are typically int and void*, might clash with other parameters

Good point, @Gene. In this library it is a void *. Worse, it is #define-d as such, not even a typedef. How would I know of the clash -- would that be a compiler error, or could it just silently pick a different pointer?

@MikhailT. If FOOHandle is not a unique type (even a typedef is just an alias not a type), then that makes things much more difficult if not impossible if any of the API functions take a void* for other purposes. You may need to define your own type to wrap any FOOHandle you pass to your wrapper just so you can identify it.

I think it is the only void *, but I'd like the compiler to tell me, if I'm mistaken. Would it? Or would it quietly take the first void * from the args...?

@MikhailT. std::tie() returns a std::tuple, which can have a type repeated multiple times. However, std::get() will fail to compile if you request a type that is repeated.

You can manually unpack the template parameters until you find the handle, eg:
FOOHandle getfoohandle() {
    return nullptr; // or whatever constitutes an "invalid" handle...
}

FOOHandle getfoohandle(FOOHandle h, auto&&...) {
    return h;
}

FOOHandle getfoohandle(auto&&, auto&&... args) {
    return getfoohandle(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
}

static void wrapper(const auto &foofunc, auto&&... args) const
{
    auto code = foofunc(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    if (code != 0) {
        FOOHandle handle = getfoohandle(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        throw FOOException(handle, code);
    }
}

Online Demo

UPDATE: for pre-C++20 compilers, auto is not allowed in function parameters, so you will have to use template parameters instead, eg:
FOOHandle getfoohandle() {
    return nullptr; // or whatever constitutes an "invalid" handle...
}

template<typename... Args>
FOOHandle getfoohandle(FOOHandle h, Args&&...) {
    return h;
}

template<typename Param1, typename... Args>
FOOHandle getfoohandle(Param1&&, Args&&... args) {
    return getfoohandle(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
static void wrapper(const Func &foofunc, Args&&... args) const
{
    auto code = foofunc(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    if (code != 0) {
        FOOHandle handle = getfoohandle(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        throw FOOException(handle, code);
    }
}

Online Demo

don't throw a pointer, throw by value

@Gene that was a copy/paste from the OP's original code. I corrected it in my example, but you should direct the comment to the OP instead.

Sigh, trying to compile my new wrapper with std=c++17, I get error: 'auto' not allowed in function prototype. Using c++20 works for me, but my Windows-using colleagues don't have that in their VC++ compiler :(

@MikhailT. auto parameters didn't exist yet in C++17. MSVC supports C++20 starting in VS 2019 v16.11 with the /std:c++20 switch. For pre-C++20 compilers, you will have to use template parameters instead. I updated my answer to show this.

It worked for a lambda-function for me earlier...

@MikhailT. lambdas are not functions, though.  auto for lambda parameters was added in C++14, and auto for function parameters was added in C++20.

The following seems to work, even with c++17: static const auto wrapper = [](const auto &func, auto&&... args)...
